# How many tags are optimal in InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb

I am new to InfluxDB. I understand the benefits of tags, but what are the costs of tags? Specifically, should I make all columns that may be used in group by or where conditions tags?

Answer (score 0):

Tags decides the series of your data. If you have huge number of points in a series it will adversely impact your performance.

Depends on your data and performance that you are looking for you can decide which are all columns needs to be marked as tags. Another depending feature related to the query performance is retention policy. If you retain data for a very less time, you can increase the number of tags since number of points in a series will be less.

All the columns within [group by](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/#group-by-tags) clause should be tags. But [where](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/#the-where-clause) clause may contain tags or fields.